# Best way to convert and sync old handwritten notes

Tags: projects

Background:
I have gained a lot of expertise in my area of work, database.

Over the past 2 years, I have written a lot of ideas and thoughts on my paper notepads, about 5 of them.
Is there a software desktop or web version that I can use to collate all those ideas into some document and run analytics or draw a mindmap from those so as to create project ideas from those?

Currently, I know of only  two approaches:

1. Type in my laptop each of them one by one.
2. Take a photo of each of them, but I don't know how to convert from screenshots of my so-so handwriting to a highlightable text file. Something from which I can copy and paste elsewhere.

With all the advancements in technology is there a way this task can be done in a more efficient and faster manner.

Comment: Check out ocr but if your handwriting is poor then it will struggle. And ocr has been around a long time

Comment: Yes, i did search on Youtube before asking  here, Both google docs and onenote on windows laptop failed to understand my writing at all :)

Comment: The Newton by Apple was pretty good ... and don’t they have a newer app?

Comment: @SolarMike - classic.

Comment: Requests for software are likely more in the scope of [softwarerecs.se], not Workplace.

Comment: You know more today than you did when writing these notes.  Take good photos of your notes and instead of copy-pasting, then retype and possibly rephrase the text when you actually need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> With all the advancements in technology is there a way this task can be done in a more efficient and faster manner.

Not really, OCR (Optical Character Recognition) is something I have tried quite a bit, but it doesn't work well with handwriting and even with old photocopied text you have to manually check and correct.

The good thing about typing it all up is that it allows you to run everything through your mind again like a quick refresher course. Since that's what you'll probably have to do, at least there is a positive side to it.

Answer (score -1):

I would urge you to keep with paper notebooks, which is far more modern.

For people as old as me, there was a (risible) fad in the 80s? 90s? (I can't even remember, it was so long ago) to computerize!! things of that nature.

That was silly, nothing is better than physical for notes.

Some things are flawlessly suited to computerization.  Some things aren't. Tthere was a fad back there somewhere to computerized! everything.  It's an old-fashioned idea, I'd say set it aside.

Comment: I also still like taking paper notes, but from time to time reviewing and transcribing into a digital document can help or is necessary in order to share them and collaborate...

Comment: I agree taking paper notes is the way to go.  Actually forming the letters with a pen or pencil helps you recall them better than typing them on a keyboard (pressing the letter A is the same motion as pressing the letter B on the keyboard and you're not as likely to remember the keystrokes).  If you really want to get fancy you can type your handwritten notes into the computer later as a form of review and to incorporate some repetition into the process which helps you remember them better.